# keep-alive doesnt return always the last state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component, keep-alive

I have a search form which is divided into 2 parts, a first part made up of a component (which has the inputs where the user must write their search)

```
  <!-- Search Form -->
      <keep-alive>
        <searchForm />
      </keep-alive>
```

And a second part where all the functions and other functionalities of the search module are.

According to what I have been looking at, the  tag keeps the component "alive" even if the user is in another part of the application, but this partially works for me, since there are times when I return to the page, the form is compiled with the latest data (it works and other times I return and a filter that I had entered before appears, but it is not the last one (it does not work).

Comment: never use dynamic key for element keep-alive

Comment: check if `<keep-alive>` is deleted `<keep-alive>` itself must be persistent, not deleted

Comment: The [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/keep-alive.html) seems pretty clear that KeepAlive is only for wrapping dynamic components, e.g. `<component :is="activeComponent">` where "component" is not a placeholder word, it's literally the `<component>` special element.  `activeComponent` value determines which component is rendered between the KeepAlive tags.  When one dynamic component becomes inactive because another component has taken over, the inactive component's state is saved by KeepAlive in case it dynamically switches back.  That is the purpose of KeepAlive.

Comment: If your use case is not this specific scenario, you need to manually find a way to save/restore component state, such as with local storage, or a store plugin like Pinia.